# Something I've never understood in chemistry

Tags: nomenclature

I've never understood how to systematically write out IUPAC names. For example, how do I write out 6-aminohexanoic acid ? I tried searching for IUPAC related terms, but I didn't get the gist of it.

Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_name. Check the IUPAC links.

Comment: I'd recommend using @LordStryker's approach and then you can come back and edit in a specific question, after which this can be reopened.  Thanks!  Also, please try to write a more useful title, this one doesn't tell me anything about your question at first glance.